# Maui Azure B2C Login returns empty AccessToken

Tags: authentication, maui, azure-ad-b2c

I have implemented the Azure B2C authentication from [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/mobile-apps/azure-mobile-apps/quickstarts/maui/authentication) documentation. I did receive a token but my web api always returned 401. I assume, the docs are not valid for Azure B2C but only for Azure AD.

I was playing around a little bit and I found that the PublicClientApplicationBuilder class used in the described PlatformService class has a different method for setting the authority. It looks like this now:

```
var clientBuilder = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(Constants.ApplicationId)
    .WithB2CAuthority( Constants.AuthoritySignIn);
    //.WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, "common");
```

When I try to sign in now, I even get the right UserFlow. Unfortunately the return value always has an empty AccessToken and no claims.

Comment: I am not familiar with Azure but I found a project about the problem you described, here is the website: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/on-behalf-of